# P value in backward elimination > 0.05 are eliminated from the features, why do we eliminate? (multi variable linear regression)

Tags: linear-regression, p-value

In general if the p value is less than 0.05 significance level we reject the null,
In backward elimination we delete the features whose p value is greater than 0.05, why not delete the delete the terms whose p value is less.

and on what condition do the regression model calculate the p value ?

can anyone explain in simple and clear terms.

Thanks for ur time and help.

Answer (score 1):

when the p value is >.05 the significance level is <0.05,

significance level + p_value =1

so it means if high p_value less significance of the variable hence we delete that variable.

if p_value is <0.05 then significance level is > 0.95 hence we take columns with high significance i.e low p_value and del columns with high p_value

Answer (score 0):

Your answer and the assumption are not right, because in Backward Elimination the very first Step is to set SL (significance level) for your model to a constant value (usually SL = 0.05).

The answer is simple. The goal is to keep the **significant** occurrences. so if for example you set the SL = 0.1, the P_values greater 0.1 are insignificant and the P_values smaller or equal to 0.1 are considered significant.

The higher the P_value, more insignificant the predictor (occurrence) and the coefficient closer to zero (H_0). Such an occurrence is not suitable for the model to train with.